# SQL index to validate date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm modeling a case where batches of products arrive and are consumed over time.

The data looks something like the following:

#### batch_units

```
| id | batch_id | date       | quantity |
|----|----------|------------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | 2020-01-01 | 100      |
| 2  | 1        | 2020-01-01 | -5       |
| 3  | 1        | 2020-01-03 | -3       |
| 4  | 2        | 2020-02-01 | 50       |
| 5  | 2        | 2020-02-03 | -1       |
```

Each batch starts off with some quantity, which is consumed over time.

I want to ensure that any **negative quantities will always be after the initial quantity** (the positive value) for each batch.

For this I've used the following GiST index:

```
alter table batch_units
add constraint batch_units_date_overlap_check
exclude using gist (
  batch_id with =,
  (
    case when quantity >= 0
      then daterange('-infinity'::date, date, '()')
      else daterange(date, date, '[]')
    end
  ) with &&
);
```

The works for almost every case, but doesn't allow removing from the **same batch twice in the same day**. It would be ideal if it allowed for this.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching the problem correctly here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: For the case of `batch_id = 1` and the date `2020-01-01`, how do we actually know whether the negative quantity really came first or not?  Note that there no order in your SQL table; if you show us this order, we need some column to provide the ordering.

Comment: I see what you mean, that was a bit of a typo on my end. It's reasonable to assume that the first negative quantity would be at least the day after - that limitation would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to find batches which were valid, i.e. ones which do not start off with a negative number, you may use the following exists logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch_id
FROM batch_units bu1
WHERE
    quantity > 0 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM batch_units bu2
                WHERE bu2.batch_id = bu1.batch_id AND bu2.date < bu1.date AND
                      bu2.quantity < 0);
```

### Demo

The above query should benefit from the following standard B-tree index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON batch_units (batch_id, date, quantity);
```

This should allow Postgres to just do a scan of the `batch_units` table, and then quicky lookup each record against the index.

Comment: Would this be possible to implement as a constraint or index?

Comment: @J3Y I think you might have to use a trigger to get the above logic where you want it.  But, maybe there are other ways of doing this besides what I posted.

Comment: Thanks, I think for now we'll keep the constraint since it's simpler - although it comes with the limitation that 2 negative values can't have the same date. If we need more complex validation later then we may migrate to trigger validation.